# Error when converting video to Ogg, FFMPEG

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

i was building an application using laravel which need to convert video to Ogg format, using PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg, when i test on it, i get this error,

```
Class 'FFMpeg\FFMpeg\Format\Video\Ogg' not found
```

here is my code

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open(asset('/assets/1500880936860a7bac22cda073cb9c80e2e07ccb9djl.mp4'));

$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\Ogg(), '/assets/export-webm.ogv');
```

but when i check the vendor file, the Ogg file does exist, what is the problem? and how can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try to add `use FFMpeg;` on the top of the class where you use FFMpeg !

Comment: What pacakge are you using? Can you link to it?

Comment: @Maraboc i have use "use FFMpeg\FFMpeg;", but still not working

Comment: @Jerodev https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg